# Change WooCommerce Product-Page Layout

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm Trying Customize **WooCommerce** Product-page Design.

I using `woocommerce.php` page and use `<?php woocommerce_content(); ?>` for provide content on there.

So i want Customize Layout of `<?php woocommerce_content(); ?>` base of my design.
How to Change or Customize That?

How To Access To `<?php woocommerce_content(); ?>` layout?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The page design can be edited in the `wc-template-functions.php` page. It can be found in the `woocommerce/includes` folder.

Comment: Thanks @Howlin. for change layout i should change this file in plugin? or we have another better way?

Comment: If you have ftp access you can download the file and make changes to it and upload it when you are finished, or install http://wordpress.org/plugins/wpide/ <- that plugin. That will allow you to browse to that file without the need of downloading it.

Answer (score 2):

The Woocommerce team strongly suggest you modify your theme with add on files rather than edit the plugin. This process makes your work much more 'upgrade proof'

[Click here for link to Woo docs website and article...](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/)

> The template files of WooCommerce contain the markup and template structure for the front-end (and 
>   HTML emails) of your store. If you open these files you’ll notice they
>   all contain many hooks which will allow you to add / move content
>   without having to edit the template files themselves. This method
>   protects even further against any upgrade issues as the template files
>   can be left completely untouched.
>
> Alternatively, you can edit these files in an upgrade safe way through
>   overrides. Simply copy it into a directory within your theme named
>   /woocommerce, keeping the same file structure.
>
> Example: To overide the admin order notification, copy:
>   woocommerce/templates/emails/admin-new-order.php to
>   yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/admin-new-order.php The copied file will
>   now override the WooCommerce default template file. Do not edit these
>   files within the core plugin itself as they are overwritten during the
>   upgrade process and any customisations will be lost.